# What kind of object does a Parse.Query.get()

Tags: parse-platform

Using the JavaScript SDK, what kind of object would be returned on the following query:

```
var groupQuery = new Parse.Query('some_valid_class');
var group = groupQuery.get('some_valid_object_id');
console.log(group);
```

I only see [object Object] in the log.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On Cloud Code - You can't print objects directly as we usually does in console of browser.

You have to use **console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject))**

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation doesn't say so, I believe the `get` method returns a [Promise](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises). Here is an example for getting the actual object taken from the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html):

```
var query = new Parse.Query(MyClass);
query.get(myId, {
  success: function(object) {
    // object is an instance of Parse.Object.
  },

  error: function(object, error) {
    // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
  }
});
```

In the `success`-function a `Parse.Object` is provided.

You can find all the info at the [Parse JavaScript SDK & Cloud Code Reference](https://parse.com/docs/js/)

Specific Parse.Query.get() documentation here: https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#get

Comment: Thats what I thought, but it doesn't seem to be the case. The object returned does not respond to the methods a Parse.Object would, and in fact the Parse.Query documentation does not clarify what is the return of the get() method.

I should clarify that I'm testing on the Parse Cloud.

Comment: You're correct regarding the documentation omitting the return value of get(). It does say: **Constructs a Parse.Object** whose id is already known by fetching data from the server. But it doesn't actually return it, that's a Promise... Updated my answer